# What squad upgrades transfer with a Mass Effect 2 save-file import?

Tags: mass-effect-2, mass-effect-3

Credits are at a premium in Mass Effect 2, and it is impossible to research every upgrade for every weapon in the base game.

Is there any benefit imported into Mass Effect 3 by maxing your Weapon, Biotic, or Tech upgrades in a Mass Effect 2? Or can I save my credits for more frivolous things, like Fish and Space Hamsters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of your upgrades from ME2 will transfer to ME3. The only useful thing you can do before exporting a save is to wipe Shepards allocated skill points to allow you to have a fresh start in ME3.

*And Space Hamsters are **never** frivolous*.

Comment: Wiping your skills really isn't that useful, since they'll all get reset if you change class, and you only have to play one mission with them before you can change them if you stay the same class.